# setText() multiple strings from xml

Tags: java, android, settext

Maybe a simple question - I need help to setText multiple strings from my strings.xml.

```
 mytext.setText(resources.getString(R.string.history_text1+R.string.history_text2));
```

So I mean I need to put 2 different text as one via one setText.

However with this syntax I have an error: *android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xfe1e0079*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values:
`R.string.history_text1` and `R.string.history_text2`
are integer numbers referencing the actual strings in resources. 
By adding them you get another integer that references nothing, so you get:

```
Resources$NotFoundException
```

If you want to concatenate the 2 string values:

```
String value = resources.getString(R.string.history_text1) + resources.getString(R.string.history_text2)
mytext.setText(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 mytext.setText(resources.getString(R.string.history_text1) + resources.getString(R.string.history_text2))
```

Comment: I tried it also this way but then I have a warning in Android Studio: Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders.. However I am using the placeholders... BUT seems it is working this way, just the warning is appearing

Comment: add empty string to string from resources `mytext.setText("" + resources.getString(R.string.history_text1) + resources.getString(R.string.history_text2))`

Comment: that did not remove the warning. The answer from @forpas helped. But thanks anyway!